# Symfony Form CollectionType with API post of new/existing entities

Tags: php, symfony

Building an internal API endpoint which allows another service to update specific fields for users, identified by email addresses. If the user does not exist, it needs to be created.

The code is working perfectly fine providing only new users are submitted.

This is the POST request to the API endpoint.

```
[
    {
        "email":"existing@user.com",
        "favouriteFood": "pizza"
    },
    {
        "email":"new@user.com",
        "favouriteFood": "sweets"
    }
]
```

Controller action

```
public function postUsersAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(UserCollectionType::class);
    $form->submit(['users' => json_decode($request->getContent(), true)], true);

    if (!$form->isValid()) {
        return $form;
    }

    /** @var User $user */
    foreach ($form->getData()['users'] as $user) {
        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
    }

    $this->em->flush();

    return $form->getData()['users'];
}
```

UserCollectionType

```
class UserCollectionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('users', 'collection', [
            'allow_add' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'type' => UserType::class
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'csrf_protection' => false,
            'cascade_validation' => true
        ]);
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```

UserType

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email')
            ->add('favouriteFood', TextType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
            'validation_groups' => ['user_api'],
            'cascade_validation' => true
        ]);
    }
}
```

How can I update the above code so that it will check to see if the user exists first, otherwise continue to create a new one how it's currently working.

I'd have assumed a DataTransformer could have been used, but not exactly how.

**EDIT: Proposed solution by ShylockTheCamel**

Inside the controller.

```
$post = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
$users = [];

foreach ($post as $userRaw) {
    $user = $this->em->findOneBy($userRaw['email']); // example search logic in the DB

    if (!$user) {
        $user = new User();
    }

    $users[] = $user;
}

$form = $this->createForm(UserCollectionType::class, $users);
$form->submit(['users' => $post], true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your user(s) entity(ies) exist when you enter the foreach loop. So you must create them in the form creation process. In that case, why not check th existence of a user in one of your form validators?

Comment: I have updated the question with how I'd apply your proposed solution. Just feels a bit hacky so avoided this in the first place. Was curious to see if theres a better solution, such as some way of hooking into where Symfony creates the user based on 'data_class'

Comment: I didn't suggest to check the existence of a user within the controller itself (which is rather dirty indeed) but inside a validator class. I suppose you validate the form, i.e. the fields email and favoriteFood against some constraints don't you? What I suggested is adding a constraint on email to check its non-existence for example. If the test succeeds, along with your other constraint, perform your current actions for a new user. If it fails, check if the non-existence constraint failed and not the others and if that's the case, it is an existing user.

Comment: Interesting, I don't see how that would work though. How will I get a populated instance into my controllers loop seeing as validators wouldn't return any data?